# Wininet.dll Error on C# using VS2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, wininet

I have a problem on my C# codes (I'm using VS2010), I try to used wininet.dll to use it's FTP function. The DLL is not a .NET component so I was not able to add in as reference, instead I used this code I saw on the internet, here's the code:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    extern public static long InternetOpen(
        string lpszAgent,
        long dwAccessType,
        string lpszProxyName,
        string lpszProxyBypass,
        long dwFlags);
```

I didn't encounter any error when I save and build the project, but when I try debug I received an error, a part of the error says that "Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method 'InternetOpen' has no implementation (no RVA)."

I believe the error is because it can't see the actual wininet.dll file, I try to put the file in the folder where the project file is but it didn't solve the problem. Hope you guys can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you copy the code from? Do they claim it works? What is the complete exception you receive?

Comment: I forgot to copy the link but I saw it in StackOverFlow too, and the person who post the problem said that his code is working (he has a different issue but he said that his code is working)

Comment: It can never work, the declaration is completely wrong.  The error message is an unlikely one, it says that the *extern* keyword is missing.  Sounds like you're trying to do this on platform that doesn't support pinvoke at all.  FTP is already well supported by .NET, don't do it yourself.

Comment: Hans, thanks, I think that's a possibility, but what if I want to use the dll in my 4.0 project? Is there a way if wininet is a non .NET component?

Answer (score 0):

The runtime probably can't find the entry point for that signature, as according to P/Invoke.net the signature looks like this:

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr InternetOpen(string lpszAgent, 
                                  int dwAccessType, 
                                  string lpszProxyName, 
                                  string lpszProxyBypass, 
                                  int dwFlags);
```

Comment: I try to change the code according to your answer, but still the error appears

Comment: Here's the complete error msg:

Could not load type 'FTPDelete.Form1' from assembly 'FTPDelete, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method 'InternetOpen' has no implementation (no RVA).   NOTE: FTPDelete is the solution name.